# MainActivity still visable with fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

Hello guys and gals when I launch a fragment the view from my main class is still visible therefore the buttons show during the entire program.. I'm wondering what the simplest solution to this problem might be. Do I need to make a fragment for two buttons, then launch another fragment from the fragment containing the buttons? Is there a way to hide the view from the main class while the fragment is shown? Any tips are greatly appreciated I've been looking for a solution for a while now.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Arrays.sort(lContacts,Contact.ContactNameComparator);

    for(int i = 0; i< lContacts.length;i++){
        mLnames[i] = lContacts[i].getLname();

    }
    mQuoteArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Quotes);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnnames = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlaunch);
    btndepartments = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndepartments);
    btnnames.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);
    btndepartments.setOnClickListener(myhandler2);

    mTitleFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.title_fragment_container);
    mQuotesFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.quote_fragment_container);


    mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

    mFragmentManager
            .addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    setLayout();
                }
            });

}

View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.title_fragment_container,
                new TitlesFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }

};

View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

};

private void setLayout() {
    if (!mQuoteFragment.isAdded()) {
        mTitleFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)); // width, height
        mQuotesFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                MATCH_PARENT));
    } else {
        mTitleFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                MATCH_PARENT, 1f)); // width, height, weight
        mQuotesFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                MATCH_PARENT, 2f));
    }
}



@Override
public void onListSelection(int index) {
    if (!mQuoteFragment.isAdded()) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.quote_fragment_container,
                mQuoteFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
    if (mQuoteFragment.getShownIndex() != index) {
        mQuoteFragment.showIndex(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Fragment should be used if you want to add a view, and the actions that come along with it, on to the activity. And so I do not think that you can hide the Activity view or at least I don't think it is a good programming practice. So there are two solutions you can fix this:

1. Make the Fragment you have right now to another Activity
2. Make the Activity (Main class) view to be empty and have two Fragments: the one that you have right now and another one that contains the views of the Activity along with their listeners and actions. In this way, if you want to switch to the other Fragment, you just have to hide the main class view fragment.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I ended up leaving the two buttons on Mainactivity, then made a blank activity for the fragments. Thank you for the suggestions!